# Type 'Observable<Admin[]>' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

Here is my admin Interface

```
export interface Admin{
  name: string;
  email: string;
  telephone: string;
  address: string;
  nic: string;
}
```

This is my constructor

```
  constructor(
    private afs: AngularFirestore,
    private admins: Observable<Admin[]>,
    private adminDoc: AngularFirestoreCollection<Admin>
    ){
      this.adminDoc = this.afs.collection<Admin>('users/user/admin');  
      this.admins = this.adminDoc.snapshotChanges().pipe(
        map(actions => actions.map(a=>{
          var data = a.payload.doc.data() as Admin;
          const id = a.payload.doc.id;      
          return {id,...data}
        }))
      );
     }
```

This is where I get the Error

```
for(let admin of this.admins){
}
```

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 3):

this.admins is now an observable, and you cannot iterate over an observable, you will have to subscribe to it. or move the `for` loop logic inside:

```
  map(actions => actions.map(a=>{
       var data = a.payload.doc.data() as Admin;
       const id = a.payload.doc.id; 

        //====> you have access to all items of here

        return {id,...data}
   }))
```

Or subscribe to it like so:

`this.admins.subscribe(admins => console.log(admins));`